# (How) does lambda calculus encode/use associativity of function composition?

Tags: functions, category-theory, lambda-calculus

I'm just learning about Lambda Calculus, so apologies if this is an obvious question, but given how useful and fundamental the associativity property of function composition is, (how) is this associativity encoded/utilized in lambda calculus (which is apparently designed to abstract important patterns of functions)?

I'm *not* asking about the *convention* of left (or right) associativity in lambda or type notation, but the genuine and general associativity property of function composition, i.e. the general identity $f(gh)=(fg)h$.

The Hindley and Seldin bible on lambda calculus doesn't even mention associativity.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a convention. Composition associativity is not a convention but a theorem.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof that given three terms $f,g,h$ in the lambda calculus, then their composition as functions is associative? Perhaps you are confusing composition and juxtaposition in the lambda calculus?

Comment: @Couchy. Thanks. Yes, I am asking for proof you mention. Yes perhaps I am also confusing composition and juxtaposition. The confusion may have arisen because an application term MN (your "juxtposition"?) looks tantalisingly like composition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general it is not the case that given lambda terms $f,g,h$, then $(fg)h = f(gh)$. For example, let $I=\lambda x.x$, and take
$$f =\lambda x.\lambda y.x,\quad g=h = I$$
then $(fg)h = I$, however $f(gh) = \lambda y.I$.

However, you could define a composition term
$$c = \lambda f.\lambda g.\lambda x.f(gx)$$
and show that
$$((c((cf)g))h) = ((cf)((cg)h)).$$
Notice that this notation is hard to read, and for this reason it is common to associate application of lambda terms to the left, that is we can instead write
$$c(cfg)h = cf(cgh).$$

To show this we just expand $c$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
c(cfg)h &= \lambda x.(cfg)(hx)\\
&=\lambda x.(\lambda x.f(gx))(hx)\\
&=\lambda x. f(g(hx))\\
&=\lambda x.f((\lambda x.g(hx))x)\\
&=\lambda x.f((cgh)x)\\
&=cf(cgh).
\end{align*}

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks! This is helpful.